# Add a .mar library to intellij project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, rampart

Currently I am trying to include the `rampart mar` file in my project but when go to `File -> Project Structure -> Dependencies -> Add Jars or directories` and then navigate to rampart module folder, it doesn't show the `rampart-1.6.2.mar` file.

[image]

I have checked that the `module` contains `rampart-1.6.2.mar` file, but intellij is not recognizing it.

I have even tried adding it with following options:

- `File -> Project Structure -> Dependencies -> Library`
- `File -> Project Structure -> Dependencies -> Module`

I have also searched for if there is any plugin for `.mar` files,
but no luck.

How can I include `rampart.mar` file, please help.
I am using:

- Intellij 12.1.4
- rampart-1.6.2
- java-1.7

Thanks

Comment: Well a .mar file isn't a .jar file or directory so I can see why it wouldn't be found.

Comment: but there is no option for adding `.mar` file, so how can I include it.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Apache Rampart ever, but from what I just read, I don't see why you need a module file as a dependency library. You just have to put the module in the right place at deployment to test your web service. Then you test it with the IntelliJ WebServices plugin with WS Engine "Apache Axis 2" selected.

You add dependencies typically when you need files at compile time. It looks instead like `.mar` module files are a runtime dependency.

Note also that "Module" in the IntelliJ project context and "Module" in the Axis2 context are completely different things.